# pyspark pivot row without aggrefation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have Pyspark Dataframe named df as below,

[image]

I need to pivot the data based on ProducingMonth and classification column and need to produce the following output

[image]

I am using the following pyspark code

```
pivotDF = df.groupBy("WELL_ID","CLASSIFICATION").pivot("CLASSIFICATION")
```

while I am displaying the data  I am getting error "'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'display'"

Comment: You have an error that does not even match your code. Please add the missing piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the aggregation after.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

pivotDF = df.groupBy("WELL_ID","producing_month").pivot("CLASSIFICATION").agg(
   F.first("OIL"),
   F.first("GAS"),
)
```

Then you can probably use display `pivotDF.display()`